# Handling Login.Authenticate event

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication

A) Book I’m learning from says that if we handle *Login.Authenticate* event, then we have to authenticate users on our own. Thus control won’t automatically validate username and password. I thought book suggested this would only happen if we override *Login.OnAuthenticate()* method, but it appears that even if only add an event handler for *Authenticate* event, the automatic authentication doesn’t happen.

But why is that? Why doesn’t event handling work like it does with  *Init* or *Load* events, where you essentially have to override *Page.OnInit()* and *Page.OnLoad()* in order gain control over event handling?

B) I checked MSDN site and it basically recommends that if we do override *Login.OnAuthenticate()*,  we should also call *base.OnAuthenticate()*. But then, why would we ever need to override *Login.OnAuthenticate()*, if we get the same effect with simply declaring an event handler for *Login.Authenticate*?

thanx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not override [`OnAuthenticate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.onauthenticate.aspx). This method is only used internally to either raise the [`Authenticate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.authenticate.aspx) event to registered handlers if there are any or authenticate via the current `MembershipProvider` if there are no handlers registered. So, to implement custom authentication for the `Login` control, you simply register a handler for the `Authenticate` event and set the [`AuthenticateEventArgs.Authenticated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.authenticateeventargs.authenticated.aspx) property.

Event handling for the `Authenticate` event works exactly the same as for other events. The only difference is that the `OnAuthenticate` method has some logic that determines whether to use a `MembershipProvider` or a registered event handler for authentication.

If you do create a subclass of `Login` and override `Login.OnAuthenticate`, it is wise to call `base.OnAuthenticate(...)` because it contains the logic that calls the registered event handlers. If you do not call `base.Authenticate(...)`, you should call the registered event handlers yourself. But creating a subclass of `Login` is probably not necessary in your situation.

Comment: RWWILDEN - Event handling for the Authenticate event works exactly the same as for other events. The only difference is that the OnAuthenticate method has some logic that determines whether to use a MembershipProvider or a registered event handler for authentication.---

So in essence this logic notices that we registered an event handler for Authenticate event and assumes we will handle authentication ourselves and thus cancels automatic authentication?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what happens.