# Change ASP.NET Membership Provider by code

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

We are in need of supporting two Membership providers simultaneously in an ASP.NET WebFroms application. Indeed user by checking a Checkbox indicates that he/she wants to login via `Asp Net Sql Membership Provider` or `Asp Net Active Directory Membership Provider`

My idea is changing Membership provider programmatically based on Checkbox checked value. But do not know how can do this.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can use this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovidercollection.item.aspx (remember to list all providers in the web.config file) With the returned `MembershipProvider` you can use these methods: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider_methods.aspx

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I have reviewed them before. By now I'm examining Steven solution. BTW thanks for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need is a composite provider that wraps the two real providers and a service that can determine which provider should be used.

**UPDATE**

Your `CompositeProvider` might look like this and can be registered in your web.config just like any other provider.

```
public class CompositeProvider : MembershipProvider
{
    private MembershipProvider SqlProvider
    {
        get { return Membership.Providers["Sql Provider"]; }
    }

    private MembershipProvider AdProvider
    {
        get { return Membership.Providers["Ad Provider"]; }
    }

    // This property implements the logic that knows how
    // to switch between the two providers.
    private MembershipProvider Provider
    {
        get
        {
            var context = HttpContext.Current;

            if (context != null)
            {
                var session = context.Session;

                if (session != null &&
                    session["use_ad_provider"] == "true")
                {
                    return AdProvider;
                }
            }

            return SqlProvider;
        }
    }

    public override bool ChangePassword(string username, 
        string oldPassword, string newPassword)
    {
        return Provider.ChangePassword(username, oldPassword, newPassword);
    }

    public override bool DeleteUser(string username, 
        bool deleteAllRelatedData)
    {
        return Provider.DeleteUser(username, deleteAllRelatedData);
    }

    public override bool EnablePasswordReset
    {
        get { return Provider.EnablePasswordReset; }
    }

    public override bool EnablePasswordRetrieval
    {
        get { return Provider.EnablePasswordRetrieval; }
    }

    // TODO: Implementation of all other members.
}
```

Comment: I have tried but was not succeeded. Indeed I do no want to be involved in low level details of ActiveDirectory membership. I tries this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232072/mixed-mode-authentication-against-ad-and-fallback-to-the-database-if-it-fail-wit

Comment: Your update is pretty promising. I'm testing it. Due a problem in our code, it need a bit of time to say if it was the answer or not. Thanks in advance.

Comment: thanks for your solution. It did work finally. One of problems in our own base code was wrong using of `Login.Authenticate event`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821395/handling-login-authenticate-event

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially the same answer as [Steven's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16105261/396), but with a fully implemented class (to save someone else the time of writing this all out).

```
public class CompositeProvider : MembershipProvider
{

    public override string ApplicationName
    {
        get
        {
            return _provider.ApplicationName;
        }
        set
        {
            _provider.ApplicationName = value;
        }
    }

    private MembershipProvider _provider
    {
        get
        {
            // Insert your logic here to change between multiple providers
            if(SomeCondition == true)
                return Membership.Providers["AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"];
            else
                return Membership.Providers["AspNetSqlMembershipProvider2"];
        }
    }

    public override bool ChangePassword(string username, string oldPassword, string newPassword)
    {
        return _provider.ChangePassword(username, oldPassword, newPassword);
    }

    public override bool ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer(string username, string password, string newPasswordQuestion, string newPasswordAnswer)
    {
        return _provider.ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer(username, password, newPasswordQuestion, newPasswordAnswer);
    }

    public override MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, string password, string email, string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved, object providerUserKey, out MembershipCreateStatus status)
    {
        return _provider.CreateUser(username, password, email, passwordQuestion, passwordAnswer, isApproved, providerUserKey, out status);
    }

    public override bool DeleteUser(string username, bool deleteAllRelatedData)
    {
        return _provider.DeleteUser(username, deleteAllRelatedData);
    }

    public override bool EnablePasswordReset
    {
        get { return _provider.EnablePasswordReset; }
    }

    public override bool EnablePasswordRetrieval
    {
        get { return _provider.EnablePasswordRetrieval; }
    }

    public override MembershipUserCollection FindUsersByEmail(string emailToMatch, int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
    {
        return _provider.FindUsersByEmail(emailToMatch, pageIndex, pageSize, out totalRecords);
    }

    public override MembershipUserCollection FindUsersByName(string usernameToMatch, int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
    {
        return _provider.FindUsersByName(usernameToMatch, pageIndex, pageSize, out totalRecords);
    }

    public override MembershipUserCollection GetAllUsers(int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
    {
        return _provider.GetAllUsers(pageIndex, pageSize, out totalRecords);
    }

    public override int GetNumberOfUsersOnline()
    {
        return _provider.GetNumberOfUsersOnline();
    }

    public override string GetPassword(string username, string answer)
    {
        return _provider.GetPassword(username, answer);
    }

    public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)
    {
        return _provider.GetUser(username, userIsOnline);
    }

    public override MembershipUser GetUser(object providerUserKey, bool userIsOnline)
    {
        return _provider.GetUser(providerUserKey, userIsOnline);
    }

    public override string GetUserNameByEmail(string email)
    {
        return _provider.GetUserNameByEmail(email);
    }

    public override int MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts
    {
        get { return _provider.MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts; }
    }

    public override int MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters
    {
        get { return _provider.MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters; }
    }

    public override int MinRequiredPasswordLength
    {
        get { return _provider.MinRequiredPasswordLength; }
    }

    public override int PasswordAttemptWindow
    {
        get { return _provider.PasswordAttemptWindow; }
    }

    public override MembershipPasswordFormat PasswordFormat
    {
        get { return _provider.PasswordFormat; }
    }

    public override string PasswordStrengthRegularExpression
    {
        get { return _provider.PasswordStrengthRegularExpression; }
    }

    public override bool RequiresQuestionAndAnswer
    {
        get { return _provider.RequiresQuestionAndAnswer; }
    }

    public override bool RequiresUniqueEmail
    {
        get { return _provider.RequiresUniqueEmail; }
    }

    public override string ResetPassword(string username, string answer)
    {
        return _provider.ResetPassword(username, answer);
    }

    public override bool UnlockUser(string userName)
    {
        return _provider.UnlockUser(userName);
    }

    public override void UpdateUser(MembershipUser user)
    {
        _provider.UpdateUser(user);
    }

    public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        return _provider.ValidateUser(username, password);
    }
}
```