# Using database or Active Directory authentication in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, active-directory

We are using the ASP.NET AD authentication via `<asp:Login>` container. I'd like to add some functionality to either do AD authentication (which currently works without me generating code) or database authentication.

I handled the `Authenticate` event to optionally make the database call if configured in the `web.config`, however it seems to be all or nothing. Either I have to do both the AD and the database authentication by code or just use AD. Can I handle the database stuff and pass thru AD authentication and let the system handle it (e.g. how it is doing it now behind the scenes?).

The problem is right now I do not have any code to handle the AD stuff, so if I am using AD, then the handled event is called, the auth variable is populated to false, and the login fails. I'd like to do the AD stuff but not necessarily write a bunch of code (if I have to that is fine).

Here is my asp.net code.

```
  <asp:Login id="ADLogin" runat="server" destinationpageurl="Summary.aspx" width="250px" ForeColor="White"
    DisplayRememberMe="False" 
        remembermetext="Remember me next time on this computer" titletext="" 
    usernamelabeltext="User Name: " passwordlabeltext="Password: " 
        onloggedin="ADLogin_LoggedIn" onloginerror="ADLogin_LoginError" 
        onloggingin="ADLogin_LoggingIn" 
        onauthenticate="ADLogin_Authenticate">
  </asp:Login>
```

Here is my c# code for the event.

```
    protected void ADLogin_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        // i am not sure if i want to rewrite all of the AD stuff.
        bool useAD = (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UseActiveDirectory"].ToString() == "true") ? true : false;
        bool auth = false;

        if (!useAD)
        {
            auth = IsDatabaseUser(ADLogin.UserName, ADLogin.Password);
        }
        else // call base method?? (or something??)
        {

        }

        e.Authenticated = auth;
    }
```

Comment: Also this post is somewhat helpful, but as far as I can tell does not come up with a solution to do what I need (call internal method to handle AD authentication from the handled OnAuthenticate event)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821395/handling-login-authenticate-event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think programaticaly handling AD codes ( your own) is a good attempt. but asp.net provider model is an outstanding practice. you can extend the provider model. the following links provides you what you actually looking.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650308.aspx

Comment: Thanks, to clarify, I did the steps on this page already, so AD authentication does work.  However I think I need to handle the onauthenticate event to use either database or AD authentication, and here is where I get lost, it seems I have to code for both AD and database authentication if I handle that event.

Comment: Rob, let me know i understood your problem correctly. I think you have to integrate AD authentication also some custom authentication with your own logic also rob check this link    http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/265870/Bypass-Forms-Authentication-to-Use-Active-Director

Comment: Thanks for the link, this got me to where I wanted to be.  I did need a small procedure to do the AD lookup.